# Edit content in header of document Python-docx

Tags: xml, python-docx

I am trying to find and replace text in **a Textbox in Header** of document. But after searching for awhile, it seems there is no way to access the content in the Header or "float" text boxes via python-docx (I read issue [here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/413))

So, it means we have to find and replace directly on the xml format of document. Do you know anyway to do that?

Comment: Lots of people do this using XSLT. The only difficulties are (a) you have to learn the basics of XSLT, and (b) you have to master the weirdness of the docx vocabulary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem. For instance, I have a `template.docx` file, and I want to change text in **a Textbox in Header** as described above. Flow steps below, I solved my problems:

1. Rename file `template.docx` to `template.zip`
2. Unzip `template.zip` to `template` folder
3. Find and replace text I want to change in one of the `header<number>.xml` files in `/template/word/` folder.
4. Zip all files in `/template` folder back to `template.zip`
5. Rename `template.zip` back to `template.docx`

I used Python to manipulate these

```py
import os
import shutil
import zipfile

WORKING_DIR = os.getcwd()
TEMP_DOCX = os.path.join(WORKING_DIR, "template.docx")
TEMP_ZIP = os.path.join(WORKING_DIR, "template.zip")
TEMP_FOLDER = os.path.join(WORKING_DIR, "template")

# remove old zip file or folder template
if os.path.exists(TEMP_ZIP):
    os.remove(TEMP_ZIP)
if os.path.exists(TEMP_FOLDER):
    shutil.rmtree(TEMP_FOLDER)

# reformat template.docx's extension
os.rename(TEMP_DOCX, TEMP_ZIP)

# unzip file zip to specific folder
with zipfile.ZipFile(TEMP_ZIP, 'r') as z:
    z.extractall(TEMP_FOLDER)

# change header xml file
header_xml = os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER, "word", "header1.xml")
xmlstring = open(header_xml, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
xmlstring = xmlstring.replace("#TXTB1", "Hello World!")
with open(header_xml, "wb") as f:
    f.write(xmlstring.encode("UTF-8"))

# zip temp folder to zip file
os.remove(TEMP_ZIP)
shutil.make_archive(TEMP_ZIP.replace(".zip", ""), 'zip', TEMP_FOLDER)

# rename zip file to docx
os.rename(TEMP_ZIP, TEMP_DOCX)
shutil.rmtree(TEMP_FOLDER)
```

Comment: One can iterate over multiple header files with glob.glob(os.path.join(TEMP_FOLDER, "word", "header*.xml"))

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, in memory:

```
def docx_setup_header(doc_sio_1, new_title):
    """
    Returns a StringIO having replaced #TITLE# placeholder in document header with new_title
    :param doc_sio_1:  A StringIO instance of the docx document.
    :param new_title:  The new title to be inserted into header, replacing #TITLE# placeholder
    :return: A new StringIO instance, with modified document.
    """

    HEADER_PATH = 'word/header1.xml'

    doc_zip_1 = zipfile.ZipFile(doc_sio_1, 'r')
    header = doc_zip_1.read(HEADER_PATH)
    header = header.replace("#TITLE#", new_title)

    doc_sio_2 = StringIO.StringIO()
    doc_zip_2 = zipfile.ZipFile(doc_sio_2, 'w')
    for item in doc_zip_1.infolist():
        content = doc_zip_1.read(item.filename)
        if item.filename == HEADER_PATH:
            doc_zip_2.writestr(HEADER_PATH, header, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        else:
            doc_zip_2.writestr(item, content)

    doc_zip_1.close()
    doc_zip_2.close()

    return doc_sio_2
```

Note that Python's zipfile cannot replace or delete items, so you need to make up a brand new zipfile, and copy unchanged elements from original.