# How can I find and replace a text in footer of word document using "Python docx"

Tags: python, docx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPvb.png)I have created a word document and added a footer in that document using python docx. But now I want to replace text in the footer.

For example: I have a paragraph in footer i.e "Page 1 to 10". I want to find word "to" and replace it with "of" so my result will be "Page 1 of 10".

My code:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
section = document.sections[0]
footer = section.footer
footer.add_paragraph("Page 1 to 10")
document.save('mydoc.docx')
```

​

Comment: I imagine that you mean you want to find word "to" and replace it with "of", right? Instead of the other way around as you have written.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit content in header of document Python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228136/edit-content-in-header-of-document-python-docx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution. 
You would have to iterate over all the footers in document

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('mydoc.docx')
for section in document.sections:
    footer = section.footer
    footer.paragraphs[1].text  = footer.paragraphs[1].text.replace("to", "of")

document.save('mydoc.docx')
```

The reason why this code is editing the second element of the footer paragraphs list is because you have added another paragraph to the footer in your code. By default there is an empty paragraph already in the footer according to the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section._Footer)

Comment: Great! then you should accept the answer by clicking on the check mark that is next to the answer on the left side so that it's green

Comment: If I have a document with only 1 page then the above code is working fine. But 
1.) If document have 2 or more pages, then it repeat the same page no on every page. For example: If I have document with 3 pages, then the result should be like:
"Page 1 of 3"
"Page 2 of 3"
"Page 3 of 3"
 But I am getting the result as:
"Page 1 of 3"
"Page 1 of 3"
"Page 1 of 3"

2.)  If footer have multiple lines(not defined by me. It is already present in the word document), then the above code is not working. 

Screenshot of my document footer
Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPvb.png

Comment: 1) Is the page numbering correct when you create the document? i.e. does it say Page 1 to 3, Page 2 to 3 and so on and so forth?  If I understand correctly you have to correctly add the page numbers in python-docx they don't get automatically updated. 

2) That might be because in those documents it's not the second element of the footer that has the page number. print out the elements of the footer and then see which one you should be changing instead of the second one.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
1) Actually I am not creating document using python-docx. I have already word document in which "Page no" is correctly mentioned. I am just loading the document and trying to replace "to" to "of" by using your code.
But it change every "Page no" with "Page 1 of 3"

2) I have tried this but code executes only for 1st element 
(i.e. footer.paragraphs[0].text) and if I change it with 1,2,3 and so on then the  code gives error which is ("IndexError: list index out of range").

Comment: Can you share a sample of the document with multiple pages? Remove the content and just leave the footer there so I can see why such a problem exists.

Comment: mail id to share document?

Comment: you can provide a dropbox link or a google drive link so that if someone else has the same problem they can also look at the sample doc.

Comment: gdrive link:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/170VA90j1AWYZJHqQT26kzU4SZ1wntFKD/view?usp=sharing

In file, last two page have image only. I want to replace in only those page in  which "Page No" is present.

Comment: Ok so the suggested answer doesn't work for you because in document that you shared the page number does not appear to be in the footer section of the document as pydocx reads it. You should look at this answer so that you can change the page number footer in the .xml directly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228136/edit-content-in-header-of-document-python-docx

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question however the accepted answer changes the page number of the footer and requires editing of the XML if you want to fix that issue. Instead I have found that if you edit the text using Runs, it will keep the original format for your header/footer. https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#docx.text.run.Run

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('mydoc.docx')
for section in document.sections:
    footer = section.footer
    footer.paragraphs[1].runs[0].text  = footer.paragraphs[1].runs[0].text.replace("to", "of")

document.save('mydoc.docx')
```